# Save File Dialog (viewing Libraries) crash any & all desktop applications

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, crash, save-as

My Save File Dialog points to my Libraries folder by default in which I've registered all my useful locations (Downloads, Client Documents, Source Code, etc..) into a single view.

This is great. Except that it crashes any application that tries to save/open a file to/from this default location. So it crashes all my applications whenever I "Save As" or otherwise have to open a file through a dialog (e.g. various installers).

Viewing any folder that isn't "Libraries" works fine, no problems in explorer.exe either, just the save/load dialogs.

I am about to go insane with rage, please help!

[image]

Comment: Crash as in 'application is terminated', not as in 'application hangs for an indefinite time'?

Comment: Probably the latter, dialog doesn't finish rendering, displays "Not Responding" as soon as you interact with it, trying to close it brings down the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

[If you have locations in the Library that are on an external HDD that spins down, a network drive or external USB flash drive, the issue might be the dialog is waiting for that resource.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#1TC=windows-8) You can experiment by creating a new Library with items only from the C: drive, and then adding some external folders.

Perhaps that is part of the reason [MS deprecated the Library](http://helpnet.installshield.com/adminstudio2014/Content/ashelplibrary/TC-OSB-0856.htm), [the other reason being to push SkyDrive](https://www.howtogeek.com/167610/8-features-microsoft-removed-in-windows-8.1/). It's gone the way of Alexandria.

Comment: Great shout! unfortunately I don't have any non-C: folders in my Libraries (see edit). Also, it's quite difficult to test as the Open/Save File Dialog crashes before I can interract with it to switch folders (part of what makes it so so painful)